# How do I manipulate a variable whose name conflicts with PDB commands?

Tags: python, pdb

My code is, for better or worse, rife with single letter variables (it's physics stuff, so those letters are meaningful), as well as NumPy's, which I'm often interacting with.

When using the Python debugger, occasionally I'll want to look at the value of, say, `n`.  However, when I hit `n<enter>`, that's the PDB command for `(n)ext`, which has a higher priority.  `print n` works around looking at it, but how can I set it?

Comment: Kind of overkill but have you try with `eval`? `eval('n = 3')`? Maybe it helps :)

Answer (score 182, accepted):

Use an exclamation mark `!` before a statement to have it run :

```
python -m pdb test.py
> /home/user/test.py(1)<module>()
-> print('foo')
(Pdb) !n = 77
(Pdb) !n
77
(Pdb) n
foo
> /home/user/test.py(2)<module>()
-> print('bar')
(Pdb)
```

The [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pdb.html#pdbcommand-!) say:

> #### [`! statement`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pdb.html#pdbcommand-!)
>
> Execute the (one-line) *statement* in the context of the current stack frame. The exclamation point can be omitted unless the first word of the statement resembles a debugger command. [...]

Comment: IMO it would've been more user-friendly for *commands* to require ! or some such prefix.

Answer (score 13):

You can use semicolons, so just put something else in front of it:

```
ipdb> print n
2
ipdb> n
> 145 <some code here>
  146
  147

ipdb> 1; n=4
1
ipdb> print n
4
```

Comment: A functional workaround, but I believe '!' is the operator intended to deal with this case.

Answer (score 4):

Use brackets `(variable_name)`.

For example, if you have one variable named `q`, and you want to check out its value.
If you directly input `q` in the prompt, then the `ipdb` debugging process will quit and break up.

```py
>>> q
```

Instead, you should input `(q)` to check this variable:

```py
>>> (q)
```

Then its value will be printed.

Answer (score 2):

That is not the direct answer to your question, but it may help you: [PuDB](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pudb/) is a console-based visual interface for PDB which separates commands from variable manipulation by design.

Comment: Looks interesting; I'll have to take a stab at it when I have time to learn

Answer (score 0):

Eric IDE, Wing IDE & Spyder to mention just a few all have visual debuggers that are worth a go as they separate the display of values from the commands.

Comment: visual debuggers are usually very slow compared to debugging through console, which takes almost no time to start the debugger.

Comment: @Curious They are slower to start but are often more usable especially for those of limited experience.

Comment: For scientific work I do find Spyder's debugger handy. I don't think debugging a 10x10 matrix is practical on the CLI