# Interrupt a Python function and manipulate the variables

Tags: python, scope, interrupt

I have the file `main.py` containing the code

```
def my_function():

    a = 0
    b = 1
    c = 2

if __name__ == "__main__":
    my_function()
```

I execute this script from a terminal / shell.

If I run the script with `python -i main.py` all the variables are already gone because the function `my_function` has ran out of scope.

How do I interrupt the running of the script after the command `a = 0` and set `a` to the value 1?

**EDIT**
My goal with this question is to learn how I can apply some commands on variables that are the result of a function, even after the function has finished. So the code I wrote above is just a (minimum working) example.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [Python debuger's](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pdb.html) `set_trace()` to break into the debugger from a running program and manipulate variables.
Use debugger command [c(ont(inue))](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pdb.html#pdbcommand-continue) to continue execution.

```
def my_function():

    a = 0
    import pdb
    pdb.set_trace()
    b = 1
    c = 2

if __name__ == "__main__":
    my_function()
```

Comment: Didn't know the `set_trace()` command yet. Very useful. Though I'm not sure how to manipulate the variables I must say. I'm not sure how to use the `run` and `p` command as explained at https://docs.python.org/3/library/pdb.html#pdbcommand-continue

Comment: When you break into debugger you can write Python code like `a=4`, `print(a)` or whatever you want and then just use the continue command to continue execution.

Comment: Your suggestion does not seem to work. No matter how I try to manipulate `a`, it's value remains equal to 0 if I run `print(a)`.

Comment: This did not occur to me straight away but variable named `a` conflicts with PDB commands so to change it you must use an exclamation mark ! before a statement (`!a = 4`). More about it [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21123473/how-do-i-manipulate-a-variable-whose-name-conflicts-with-pdb-commands).